# How to get the featured image inside of a single-.php template?

Tags: post-thumbnails, single

This should be easy right? I'm in the single template file for a custom post type, and this is what I have:

```
<?php
$featured = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' );
$html = '';
if(has_post_thumbnail()) :
   $html_out .= '<img src="' . $featured . '" />';
endif;
echo $html_out;
?>
```

On the front-end it outputs as `src(unknown)`. I tried `the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' )` instead, and it output the url, but it did so outside of my div, like it was just put into a random spot.

I am unsure to what I'm doing incorrectly here. Am I supposed to get the featured image some other way?

When I tried a `var_dump` on `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` I got `bool(false)`.

Comment: read the manual https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you

```
if(has_post_thumbnail())
{ 
     the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
}
```

Reference :  [Featured Images & Post Thumbnails](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/)